# How can a ForEach loop in LINQ know about the values in the prior iteration of the loop?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numeric values, each dated, like this:

```
Date       Value
--------   -----
3/5/2017   2
3/6/2017   2
3/7/2017   3
3/8/2017   3
3/9/2017   3
3/10/2017  4
```

You can see that we were at "2" for two days, then escalated to "3" for three days, then got to "4" on the sixth day.

Using LINQ, it's easy to show the date on which we achieved a record:

```
values.GroupBy(x => x.Value).OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    var record = x.OrderBy(x1 => x1.Date).First();
    Console.WriteLine(
      $"New record of {x.Key} on {record.Date.ToShortDateString()}"
    );
});
```

This outputs:

```
New record of 2 on 3/5/2017
New record of 3 on 3/7/2017
New record of 4 on 3/10/2017
```

This is great, but what if I wanted to do this:

```
New record of 2 on 3/5/2017
New record of 3 on 3/7/2017 (took 2 days)
New record of 4 on 3/10/2017 (took 3 days)
```

Each iteration of that `ForEach` loop is going to have to know the value of the last iteration in order to calculate the difference. How would this be possible?

**Answer:**

The answer is selected below, but here's my actual implementation using `Aggregate`:

```
values.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Aggregate((a, b) =>
{
    if (b.Value > a.Value)
    {
        $"New record of {b.Value} on {b.Date.ToShortDateString()} (took {b.Date.Subtract(a.Date).Days} day(s))".Dump();
        return b;
    }
    return a;
});
```

This results:

```
New record of 3 on 3/7/2017 (took 2 day(s))
New record of 4 on 3/10/2017 (took 3 day(s))
```

Note that the "baseline" of 2 isn't listed there, which is fine for my purposes.

The key to `Aggregate` is that it can be written to functionally work through the enumeration in bi-grams -- groups of two.  So:

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
```

In many cases, you combine those two things, then return the combination. But there's no reason why you can't just *compare* them, and return one or the other. That's what I did -- I compared them, and then returned the new record if it *was* a new record, otherwise I returned the existing record.

Comment: Aggregate may help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: LINQ does not seem to be the best way to solve this...

Comment: Did you try convert it to `Lookup` instead of `List` and then get the items count and write to console?

Comment: @PlayDeezGames Dude, you're right -- thank you. I have the solution using `Aggregate`. If you put it in an answer, I'll select it as _the_ answer.

Comment: OrderBy and Aggregate seems like a bit of overkill if you just need the number of dates in each group, or the days b-n the min and max dates of each group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider Aggregate:

```
values.Aggregate(new Tuple<int,int?>(0,null), (acc, e) => 
{
    if(acc.Item2==null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"New record of {e.Value} on {e.Date.ToShortDateString()}");
        return new Tuple<int, int?>(1, e.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        if(e.Value!=acc.Item2.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"New record of {e.Value} on {e.Date.ToShortDateString()} (took {acc.Item1} days)");
            return new Tuple<int, int?>(1, e.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Tuple<int, int?>(acc.Item1+1, acc.Item2);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `Aggregate` was the right answer, but I put my actual solution in the question above.

Comment: @Deane if you have a better approach you can upvote PlayDeegames and accept your solution as an answer it's doable in SO

Answer (score 1):

You have a few redundant statements in your LINQ query, which may cause performance issues down the road.  Thankfully though you don't have to LINQ all the things.  Good 'ol `foreach` is still useful:

```
//Iterate through all groups
foreach(var group in values.GroupBy(x => x.Value))
{
    //sort the records by date
    var records = group.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();

    //Grab the first record
    var firstRecord = records.First();

    if(records.Count > 1)
    {
        //Gets diff in days between first and last
        int dayCount = (firstRecord.Date - records.Last()).TotalDays;
        Console.WriteLine($"New record of {firstRecord.Key} on {firstRecord .Date.ToShortDateString()} took {dayCount} days");
    }
    else
    {            
        Console.WriteLine($"New record of {firstRecord.Key} on {firstRecord .Date.ToShortDateString()}");
    }        
}
```

Comment: I think you are a bit over the goal of OP the challenge here is clear doing this in linq !